# duplicated account login checking in server

Tags: c++, multithreading

The communication is based on socket and the it is keep-alive connection. User use account name to log in, I need to implement a feature when two user use same account to log in, the former one need to be kicked off. 
Codes need to updated:

```
void session::login(accountname) // callback when server recv login request
{
    boost::shared_ptr<UserData> d = database.get_user_data(accountname);
    this->data = d;
    this->send(login success);
}

boost::shared_ptr<UserData> Database::get_user_data(accountname)
{
    // read from db and return the data
}
```

The most simple way is improve Database::get_user_data(accountname)

```
boost::shared_ptr<UserData> Database::get_user_data(accountname)
{
    add a boost::unqiue_lock<> here
    find session has same accountname or find user data has same accountname in cache,
    if found, then kick this session offline first, then execute below codes
    // read from db and return the data
}
```

This modification has 2 problems:

1, too bad concurrency because the scenario happen rarely. However, if I need to check account online or not, I must cache it somewhere(user data or session), that means I need to write to a container which must has exclusive lock whatever the account same or not. So the concurrency can hardly improved.

2, kick other one off by calling "other_session->offline()" in "this thread" that might concurrent with other operations executing in other thread at same time.
If I add lock in offline(), that will result in all others function belong to session also need to add that lock, obviously, not good. Or, I can push a event to other_session, and let other_session handle the event, that will make sure "offline" executing in its own thread. But the problem is that will make offline executing async, codes below "other one offline" must executed after "offline" runs complete.

I use boost::asio, but I try to describe this problem in common because I think this is a common problem in server writing. Is there a pattern to solve this? Notice that this problem gets complex when there are N same account log in at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this scenario rarely happens, I wouldn't worry about it. lock and release of mutex are not long actions the user would notice (if you had to do it thousands of times a second it could be a problem).

In general trying to fix performance issues that are not there is a bad idea.